# Migrations fails on Django 1.11.20 with ugettext() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'

Tags: django-models, django-migrations

I tried to make a migrations on a Django project version 1.11.20.
But I have a error that I don't understand where it from.

They must had some migration before because the project work, I just can't add some modification to the project and apply a migration

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 193, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 231, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 163, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 120, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 72, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 293, in serialize
    return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 44, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 229, in serialize
    return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 101, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 332, in serializer_factory
    value = force_text(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 119, in __text_cast
    return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
TypeError: ugettext() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It's impossible to provide a definitive answer to your question without seeing the relevant code, so please post a proper minimal reproducile example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This being said, my crystal ball suggests that somewhere in your model files you have a call to `ugettext()` in a model field (very probably for the field's label) that is not closed at the right place so it reads something like `myfield = models.SomeField(_("foo", default=""))`  instead of `myfield = models.SomeField(_("foo"), default="")`.

Comment: I thought it was this too, and with a quick search, I didn't find something (more than 180 result, I admit I read diagonally.  ). But yes, I search more deeply and it's that ! Thks !!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers WOW. brilliant. Thanks.